# I'm trying to make a zoom in effect on the background when hovering

Tags: css, html, bootstrap-4

So i was trying to make a hover effect on the image background and after doing so I try adding an overlay using "before" to latter add some text on it, my problem is that the overlay seens to be covering the container instead of the parent element, that would be the Cimg1 class, and then when i hover it works as intended but when i stop hovering it changes position again.

```css
.Tsize{
    width: 270px;
    height: 270px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 70px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.Cimg1{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/assets.searsucker.com/content/uploads/2015/02/07172833/sandiego_thumb-253x199.png);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    transition: all .5s;
}

.Tsize:hover .Cimg1,
.Tsize:focus .Cimg1 {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.Cimg1:before{
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(19, 20, 20, 0.6);
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row no-gutters">
      
        <div class="col-4">
          <div class="Tsize">
            <div class="Cimg1">
              
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-4">
          
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-4">
          
        </div>
      
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `position:relative;` on your `.Cimg1` as your parent element.

```
.Cimg1{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/assets.searsucker.com/content/uploads/2015/02/07172833/sandiego_thumb-253x199.png);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    transition: all .5s;
    position:relative;
}
```

As you used `position:absolute;` on your `.Cimg1:before`

> **position:absolute;** is positioned relative to its first positioned (not static) ancestor element